# Use of unresolved identifier 'imageFromCameraRoll'

Tags: swift, xcode

I got an error,Use of unresolved identifier 'imageFromCameraRoll' .Now I am making a system which I can access camera roll in my app.
I wrote in SendController  like

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class SendController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: [String: AnyObject]) {


        if didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] != nil {
            imageFromCameraRoll.image = didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage


        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

I wrote in PhotoSendController like

```
import UIKit

class PhotoSendController:UIViewController,
UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
    @IBAction func ButtonCamera(_ sender: UIButton) {
                    openPicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary)

    }


    @IBAction func pressCameraRoll(_ sender: Any) {
        pickImageFromLibrary() 
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var imageFromCameraRoll: UIImageView!

    //定数
    let ButtonCamera = 0
    let ButtomRead = 1
    let ButtonWrite = 2


    //変数
    var imageView:UIImageView  = UIImageView()
    var btnCamera:UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var btnRead:UIButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var btnWrite:UIButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
       func onClick(sender:UIButton){
       if sender.tag == ButtonCamera {
          showAlert(title: nil, text: "利用できません")
          openPicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)


         }else if sender.tag == ButtomRead {
           openPicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary)
        }

    }

    func showAlert(title: String?, text: String?) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: text, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func openPicker(sourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceType){
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType){
            showAlert(title: nil, text: "利用できません")
            return
        }

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image
        picker.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true,completion:nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func pickImageFromLibrary() {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) { 
            let controller = UIImagePickerController()
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

First,I thought I wrote  `@IBOutlet weak var imageFromCameraRoll: UIImageView!` in PhotoSendController,but I could not select UIImageView and push control key and drag&drop PhotoSendController(usually I could do this to do same thing)But in this time I could not do it, because blue line which stick to Controller was not shown.What happen in my code?Why was not blue line shown?What can I fix this?

Comment: `PhotoSendController` is a completely different class than `SendController`. It's defined in the former, not the latter.

Comment: @AlejandroIván It means,I have to make only one class,right?Do you think I do not need SendController?In this case,I cannot write codes in 2 classes,can't I?

Comment: you dont need SendController in this case